# Trouble in getting activities from directline API after one day

Tags: azure, direct-line-botframework

Calling API with the conversation Id to get all the activities and the conversation had done on the 24-04-20 03:45 PM when I called on same day I'm getting response but after one day it is sending empty array of activities in response. Below is the API which I am calling.

https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/7v4dGpYTj9QH3W0ns4jOzi-6/activities

The reference doc link which I am following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#http-get

I've tried multiple conversations.

Comment: I think this question would be clearer if you gave some more detail about what you are trying to achieve, what the process flow looks like, perhaps some basic sample code, and a link to the API docs that you are referring to. The link you have given in the post just tells us we are missing an access token.

Comment: @guysherman I have updated the question, i.e. added reference doc. For access token you need to pass a authorization header with secret key or token (obtained from azure) as mentioned in doc. For more details about how to get secret follow [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: Still need some sample code, process flow, etc.